# Wordpress PHP fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress

Customers cannot access their account details, and are met with the following error:

**Fatal error:** Call to undefined function validate_form_data() in /wpsc-account-edit-profile.php on line 14

This is from wpsc-account-edit-profile.php

```
<form method="post">

<?php echo validate_form_data(); ?>

<table>

    <?php wpsc_display_form_fields(); ?>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="true" name="submitwpcheckout_profile" />
            <input type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Save Profile', 'wpsc' ); ?>" name="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Specifically Line 14:

```
<?php echo validate_form_data(); ?>
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and how it could possibly be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: What version of WP eCommerce are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `validate_form_data()` function is defined in `functions/wpsc-user_log_functions.php` so you need to ensure your WPSC theme includes the appropriate file to make the function available.

Depending on what version and theme you are using you can use the following where you setup your theme includes

```
require_once( WPSC_CORE_THEME_PATH . 'functions/wpsc-user_log_functions.php' );
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640041/how-to-validation-of-input-text-field-in-ajax?noredirect=1#comment58961736_35640041